# Dirac $\delta$-function as a limit of matrices, and eigenvalues of integral kernels.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, integral-operators

I am interested in calculating the eigenvalues of integral kernels, but I figured it would be useful to get some intuition about the simplest one first: the identity operator.

The interval $[-L,L]$ has a countable set of basis functions, so there is a sense in which the identity operator may be written as a matrix
\begin{align}
I_n = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}1&0&0&\cdots\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\\\vdots&&&\ddots\end{array}\right]
\end{align}
where $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix, and the idenity on the interval $[-L,L]$ is $\lim_{n\to\infty} I_n$. As we take the limit $L\to\infty$, the set of basis functions becomes uncountable, and the identity operator becomes a Dirac $\delta$-function. Is there a sense in which the Dirac $\delta$ may be thought of as a limit of matrices? Given the transition from countable to uncountable, I suspect not, but perhaps I am mistaken.

In any case, the matrix representation of the countable basis is nice because it provides an easy-to-understand sense in which I may identify/calculate the eigenvaleus of an operator. If the uncountable case may not be thought of as a limit of the countable case, how should I think about calculating the eigenvalues of an integral operator?

Comment: What does it mean for a set to have a countable set of basis  functions? Is this something like a fourier basis

Comment: Yes, exactly. On the interval, the basis is $e^{i k x}$ where $k = \pi n/L$, with $n\in \mathbb{N}$. On the real line $(-\infty,\infty)$, $k$ takes all real values.

Comment: The $\delta$ is not the identity, but its kernel. Yes, you can see operators as infinite matrices. If you have a coutable basis $\psi_j$, then you can just write $$\sum \lambda_{i,j} \pi_{i, j}$$ where $\pi$ is a projector of $\psi_j$ to $\psi_i$. If not, you can always just think of the kernel of the operator  as the $(x,y)$ coefficient of the matrix.

Comment: Perhaps I'll be more specific. I have a kernel with a representation as $\delta(x - x') + \text{finite part}(x,x')$, and I want to compute its eigenvalues. Do you have any suggestions?